# Azure function app native module DLL initialization error

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I need to use a native module scrypt in my function app.

I have installed the module via the kudu console. (I had to had to install globally and then copy to the local `node_modules` directory. Installing locally resulted in a strange LINK error)

I can run scrypt tests on the local install and they pass.
However, when I try to `require('scrypt')` from within the azure function, I get this error:

> mscorlib: One or more errors occurred. Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Node native modules are not currently supported in Azure Functions.

This is something that will be addressed in the next major version of the runtime, but currently, it is a limitation.

Comment: is there a timeline for the next major version and adding that functionality?

Comment: No officially announced dates at this point. We do have a preview available and you can find more information here :  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/09/25/develop-azure-functions-on-any-platform/