# Azure Function - NodeJs - Sqlite - mscorlib - Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: node.js, sqlite, azure, azure-functions

I have nodejs azure function that using sqlite3 lib. after running the function. i got this error.

```
2017-10-12T10:49:16.036 Function started
2017-10-12T10:49:19.434 Exception while executing function: Functions.sqlite. 
mscorlib: One or more errors occurred. Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) 
initialization routine failed.
 \\?\D:\home\site\wwwroot\sqlite\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node
at Error (native)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\sqlite\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:4:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10).
2017-10-12T10:49:19.449 Function completed (Failure, Duration=3415ms)
```

any idea how to solve this error?

Comment: As mentioned in [@Fabio Cavalcante's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46651477/azure-function-app-native-module-dll-initialization-error/46658497#46658497), "*Node native modules are not currently supported in Azure Functions*".

Comment: yeah after a long research I found that,  but still, there is lib I found and it works with azure functions.
https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem using Sql.js lib 
https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/